# Testing timer which calls function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, timer, nstimer

The method `someFunc()` is called after the brackets. I need it to be called right after the `sleep` method (exactly after the time passes). It seems that the timer calls the execution block after the `testTimer()` goes out of the brackets (which fails the test).

```
var value: String?

func testTimer() {
    let timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { timer in
            self.someFunc()
        }

    sleep(2)
    XCTAssertNotNil(value)
}

func someFunc() {
    value = "someValue"
}
```

The need for this is because I'm working with higher order functions and I need to have an outer function (which would be called regularly in the app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the [`wait(for:timeout:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/2806856-wait) method.

Keep an instance of `XCTestExpectation` in your test case:

```
let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "value not nil")
```

In your `someFunc`, fulfil that expectation:

```
expectation.fulfill()
```

And in your test method, you do:

```
let timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { timer in
        self.someFunc()
    }

wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2)
```